# How do I ignore PyCharm configuration files in a git repository?

Tags: python, git, pycharm

I don't want to commit my PyCharm config files (e.g. .idea/codeStyleSettings.xml) to my git repository, so I added the following to my .gitignore file:

```
.idea/
mydjangosite/.idea/
```

However, every time I try to make a commit within PyCharm (command k), it still wants to commit these files. How do I get PyCharm to recognize my .gitignore file and not commit these files?

Comment: I think you need a wildcard after those (`*`) - after you've committed that, it should be good. You can also add those to your global ignore so you don't have to configure your `.gitignore` every time :)

Comment: That's not correct. According to the man page for gitignore: If the pattern ends with a slash, it is removed for the purpose of the following description, but it would only find a match with a directory. In other words, foo/ will match a directory foo and paths underneath it, but will not match a regular file or a symbolic link foo (this is consistent with the way how pathspec works in general in git).

Answer (score 81, accepted):

If PyCharm offers you to commit the files, it means that you have already added them to Git. You need to remove them using 'git rm --cached' and commit the change. After that, they will be ignored by the integration according to your .gitignore settings.

Comment: The full syntax to remove recursively ".idea" directory: "git rm --cached -r .idea"

Answer (score 14):

You can [configure ignored files](http://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/webhelp/configuring-ignored-files.html).

> Under the Version Control node, of the Settings dialog box, click Ignored Files. The Ignored Files dialog box opens.

More easily:

> Tip
>
> You can also add files to ignore list on-the-fly. A new file under the Unversioned Files change list, has Ignore command on its context menu.

Comment: But there's no way to have it respect .gitignore?

Comment: For some reason this is still not working. I first tried ignoring the directory, which didn't work, then I tried ignoring the specific file, and that still didn't work.

Comment: Ignore settings: http://skitch.com/jamieforrest/8y2ny/ignore-settings Commit Dialog: https://skitch.com/jamieforrest/8y2np/commit-dialog

Answer (score 1):

- Remove the .idea folder (keep a copy)
- Commit the changes

Add the following to the gitignore

(JetBrains recommended exclusions for PyCharm that also covers JetBrains plugins etc):

```
### JetBrains ###
# Covers JetBrains IDEs: IntelliJ, RubyMine, PhpStorm, AppCode, PyCharm, CLion, Android Studio and Webstorm
# Reference: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/206544839

# User-specific stuff: .idea/workspace.xml .idea/tasks.xml .idea/dictionaries .idea/vcs.xml .idea/jsLibraryMappings.xml

# Sensitive or high-churn files: .idea/dataSources.ids .idea/dataSources.xml .idea/dataSources.local.xml .idea/sqlDataSources.xml .idea/dynamic.xml .idea/uiDesigner.xml

# Gradle: .idea/gradle.xml .idea/libraries

# Mongo Explorer plugin: .idea/mongoSettings.xml

## File-based project format:
*.iws

## Plugin-specific files:

# IntelliJ /out/

# mpeltonen/sbt-idea plugin .idea_modules/

# JIRA plugin atlassian-ide-plugin.xml

# Crashlytics plugin (for Android Studio and IntelliJ) com_crashlytics_export_strings.xml crashlytics.properties crashlytics-build.properties fabric.properties

### JetBrains Patch ###
# Comment Reason: https://github.com/joeblau/gitignore.io/issues/186#issuecomment-215987721

# *.iml
# modules.xml
# .idea/misc.xml 
# *.ipr
```

- Now you can add your .idea folder back into your project directory and the changes won't be tracked any more.

Answer (score 1):

You should not ignore all of the files under `.idea` directory. Some of them are local and tied to your personal preferences and some other are global settings of the PyCharm project that most likely should be stored in git.

Here is the link to an updated [`.gitignore` snippet for PyCharm and other JetBrains IDEs](https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/master/Global/JetBrains.gitignore).