# How to use gitignore in Pycharm?

Tags: git, pycharm, gitignore

Similar questions [like this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/936249/stop-tracking-and-ignore-changes-to-a-file-in-git) about how to ignore files in a git repo are typically answered by showing which git command to execute on the command line. [Even this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9237345/how-do-i-ignore-pycharm-configuration-files-in-a-git-repository), although it is PyCharm specific, does the same.

Is there a way to manage this file through the PyCharm GUI?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Try:

1. Go to Settings
2. Go to Plugins
3. Search for: .ignore
4. Install
5. Restart PyCharm

`.gitignore` should now be included in `.ignore` along with `.hgignore` etc.

Comment: "Settings" is under "file". Or simply Ctrl + Alt + s

Comment: But how do I add files to git ignore without having to type the name of files and folders? Like in VS Code that we right-click and click "Ignore this File".

Answer (score 14):

In PyCharm Pro 2019.3, I was able to do this by 
- right click folder or file I wanted to add to gitignore.
- scroll to and click on Git
- scroll to and click on Add to .gitignore
If a gitignore file is not already there, PyCharm will create one and add it to the main project folder and add your chosen folder/file to it.

Comment: I can't find this option on: 2021.3

Comment: You need to install it first like the accepted answer, restart you're pycharm and do as this answer said. Yes, this is frustrating, 2 answers need to be joined to make it work.

Answer (score 5):

There are plugins available in the JetBrains repository to manage this; one of them that I make use of is [.ignore](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7495?pr=idea), which allows you to have more insight into what files you're actually ignoring in the IDE.

Comment: I have that plug-in installed and it is helpful. Is it possible to manage it via the GUI?

Answer (score 3):

**Install the plugin in Pycharam professional**

```
   - Go to the right corner and click on the Settings icon
   - Now on Plugins
```

[image]

```
 - Now type the name of the plugin you want to install for example "ignore"
```

[image]

**Congatulation plugin is installed**